# Google Account with limited permissions

Tags: multiple-devices

I am trying to assess feasibility of an internal initiative at my company.

Management would like to:

- Distribute Nexus 7/10s which can have primarily calendar and contacts synced by a single Gmail account
- Disable ability to send email from this account, although not from employee's account

This is an effort to keep calendar and contacts in sync.

**Is the second requirement possible?**

Comment: Leaving this open, because it's an interesting problem.

Comment: I think you are making the problem complex. If the whole idea is to share same Calendar and Contacts then this can be achieved easily without creating another Email not sendable Gmail account. Use Google Apps and share Contacts and Calendar with the organization.

Comment: @roxan Agreed, this seems to be the best way. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

It isn't possible to limit an account to not send emails. The only solution I can think of is to sync the main account (the one for calendar and contacts) and a second account for email. In the gmail application, you have to set it to default to the second account when the application is open. In the calendar, you have to set the application to open the calendar of the main account.